# Permutation with multiple Options and different Weights

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to build a risk calculation matrix. So, when a risk is identified, this risk has ONE class for every type. There are 7 different types and 20 different classes, as per image:

every class has a different weight.

So, for instance, a risk named riskA is defined as:

1. strategic
2. biggerThan20
3. business
4. yes
5. yes
6. yes
7. yes

Then, the combination of these would have weight = (10 + 30 + 20 + 70 + 40 + 60 + 50)
weight = 280

I need to know every possible combination of calculation that could be. I believe 960 combinations.
I was trying to run some javaScript code to get the results with no success. I can’t also think of an easy way to do it using excel.

Image of spreadsheet with possible values:

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

So Try this:

```
Sub Posibilities()
Dim sht As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, Bound As Long
Dim Out As Variant, lOut As Variant, Values As Variant, Delimiter As Variant, Label As Variant

Set sht = Worksheets(1)
Set sht2 = Worksheets(2)

With sht
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Values = .Range("C1:C" & lRow + 1)
    Label = .Range("A1:B" & lRow)
End With

Values = OneDimension(Values)
Label = Labeling(Label)
Delimiter = SubArrays(Values)

Out = CalculateArrays(SliceArray(Values, 1, Delimiter(0) - 1), SliceArray(Values, Delimiter(0) + 1, Delimiter(1) - 1), 1)
lOut = CalculateArrays(SliceArray(Label, 1, Delimiter(0) - 1), SliceArray(Label, Delimiter(0) + 1, Delimiter(1) - 1), 2)

For i = 1 To UBound(Delimiter) - 1
    Out = CalculateArrays(Out, SliceArray(Values, Delimiter(i) + 1, Delimiter(i + 1) - 1), 1)
    lOut = CalculateArrays(lOut, SliceArray(Label, Delimiter(i) + 1, Delimiter(i + 1) - 1), 2)
Next i

'Output into Sheet(2)
For i = 1 To UBound(Out)
    sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Out(i)
    sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value = lOut(i)
Next i
sht2.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

Function CalculateArrays(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, Mode As Integer) As Variant
'Input: 2 One-Dimensional Arrays, Mode(1 for Values, 2 for String to Add Delimiter)
'Adds Values of arr1 and arr2
'Output: One-Dimensional Array arr3 with all Combinations

Dim arr3() As Variant, Counter As Long: Counter = 1
Dim Elements1 As Long, Elements2 As Long

Elements1 = UBound(arr1) - LBound(arr1) + 1
Elements2 = UBound(arr2) - LBound(arr2) + 1

ReDim arr3(1 To Elements1 * Elements2)

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        Select Case Mode
        Case 1
            arr3(Counter) = arr1(i) + arr2(j)
        Case 2
            arr3(Counter) = arr1(i) & "|" & arr2(j)
        End Select
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next j
Next i

CalculateArrays = arr3
End Function

Function SubArrays(arr1 As Variant) As Variant
'Input: One-Dimensional Array with empty Elements
'Searches for "" in arr1 (fields with no values in col c)
'Output: One-Dimensonal Array with Index of empty Fields

Dim arr2() As Variant, Count As Long: Count = 0

For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    If arr1(i) = "" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr2(Count)
        arr2(Count) = i
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
Next i

SubArrays = arr2
End Function

Function OneDimension(arr1 As Variant) As Variant
'Input: 2-Dimensional Array
'Transforms first Dimension of 2-Dimensional-Array into 1-Dimensional Array
'Output: 1-Dimensional Array

Dim arr2 As Variant

ReDim arr2(LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1))

For i = LBound(arr1, 1) To UBound(arr1, 1)
    arr2(i) = arr1(i, 1)
Next i

OneDimension = arr2
End Function

Function SliceArray(arr1 As Variant, l As Integer, r As Integer) As Variant
'Input: 1-Dimensional Array, l as LeftBound, r As RightBound
'Output: 1-Dimensional Array from l to r

Dim arr2 As Variant

ReDim arr2(l To r)

For i = l To r
    arr2(i) = arr1(i)
Next i
SliceArray = arr2
End Function

Function Labeling(arr1 As Variant) As Variant
'Input: 2-Dimensional Array (Col A:B)
'Transforms Array into 1 -Dimension and adds Delimiter in between.
'Output: 1-Dimensional Array

Dim arr2 As Variant

ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr1, 1))

For i = 1 To UBound(arr1, 1)
    arr2(i) = arr1(i, 1) & ": " & arr1(i, 2)
Next i
Labeling = arr2
End Function
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I will add a further explanation later, for now i just commented the functions. For it to work you need to have the Labels in Col `A:B` and the Data in Col `C` of the first Worksheet. It is important to seperate the Classes with an **empty** Row and Data starts in **Row 1**, not 2, so no Labels above. It will then Ouput the Combinations into Worksheet 2 with the Values and Combination as you can see in the pictures. The Function is layouted to work with any values if you follow the Input Requirements. That also means you could delete and add Categories.